# How the expanding universe model takes into account the fact that information from far objects is not what happens today?

Tags: cosmology

Different models on the universe are based on data obtained from far celestial objects, e.g. galaxies. But the light coming to us from them, comprises information on their state millions or billions of years ago.

A typical datum is the displacement towards red of the emission lines of elements. On this result is based the hypothesis that our universe expands. But how do we know whether this displacement is really due to recession of these galaxies, and not to a chance in fundamental constants of the universe during all this time? For instance, the light velocity is supposed to have changed during the universe evolution.

How the theory of the expanding universe takes into account this difference in the epoch of the data?

I don't belong to the domain of cosmology, so, I would appreciate a simple answer,  if there is.

Comment: I don't actually understand the title question.  The data from observation (of far...) are *the given*.  Our interpretation of the data may or may not be valid but a change in interpretation leaves the underlying data unchanged.

Comment: As to the final two questions, I suppose you've read *"A Universe without Expansion"*:  http://arxiv.org/abs/1303.6878

Comment: Many things are *given*. In order to predict the weather of tomorrow we don't take data from a year ago, unless we associate it with statistics or other things. I don't deal with these models of universe, I don't know their details. Do they take in consideration that these data are from epochs far back in the time, or are they used as if they were true in our days, because *this is what we see today*? This is the question, how is built the expanding universe model, does it take the *given* as is, or there are additional considerations.

Comment: As I said, my domain isn't gravitation, and I asked for an explanation which can be understood without belonging to that domain. If I were an expert in GR I wouldn't ask. Many people ask in this site questions in domains in which they are not experts. Also, I don't question the *given* I question the specific theories about which I asked.

Answer (score 0):

Cosmology is based on the Hubble parameter. The SI unit of the Hubble constant is 1/sec. For your question it is important to know that the time unit "sec." is referring to a comoving coordinate system, i.e. a coordinate system of [observers who perceive the universe as isotropic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comoving_distance#Comoving_coordinates).

That means that generally cosmological measurements are embedded in a sort of absolute time frame which is simplifying the transformation of time data. By consequence there is no mathematical problem to take into account the important time difference between emission and measurement of redshifted light of far galaxies.

However, beside this formal point of view such measurement may include numerous issues such as shown by C. Wetterich in the citation of Alfred Centauri.

Comment: Just a second, are we at rest, or are we I movement with respect to the co-moving frame? And the far galaxies, are they at rest in this frame?

Comment: See Ihle's answer to: 
[Are we comoving observers of space expansion?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/156768/are-we-comoving-observers-of-space-expansion) - Based on this answer, the question if far galaxies are comoving or not has to be calculated one by one by the means of the Hubble constant.

Comment: I am still navigating through the site that you indicated. I am trying to understand how, bottom line, this trick of introducing the co-moving frame, solves our problem that radiation from the distant galaxies is true for a huge time ago. Probably there is a smart trick, astrophysicists are no fools, but I didn't yet understand.

Comment: I saw what is a co-moving frame, what is cosmologic time, I saw Ihle's answer, but an answer to my simple question if the expanding universe model uses not actual data or *adapts them somehow* I didn't get. On the other hand from the Centauri reference I understand that we'd better think of our universe as shrinking. Is this the conclusion? I believe that the expanding universe is though the model accepted today. Bu how? Based on data of a time lost in the beginning of the universe? Astrophysicists can't be so non-cautious.

Comment: I believe that any concept of an "absolute time" has been rejected since Eddington's 1919 observational proof of 1915's General Relativity.  Also, the notion of any "beginning" for the entire universe or multiverse is not "accepted" physics, although it may (or may not) be applicable to the local universes of a multiverse of causally-separated spatial regions (or temporal iterations): Two inflationary cosmologies that do not require any beginning for a multiverse are Aguirre and Gratton's "Steady-state eternal inflation" of 2003 and Nikodem J. Poplawski's "Cosmology with torsion" of 2010-2020.