# Could there be a time dilation of 2,000,000x between Earth and other parts of the universe?

Tags: cosmology, spacetime, relativity, time-dilation

Don't ask me why, but you may be able to guess why I would ask such a question. The question is, what kind of conditions would have to be present in a universe in order for billions of years pass in the "extremities" of the universe, while only thousands of years might pass at the "center". Are there multiple ways this could be true? Are there no ways? Is there any possibility that we could live in such a universe? (Possible, not plausible.)

This may be a question that pushes at the limits of human understanding of physics (and I'm no physicist), but I thought I'd ask anyway. If it is too hard, then oh well.

Comment: This is trivially true: time dilation goes to infinity as you approach a black hole's event horizon, so you can get any time dilation factor you want by hovering an appropriate distance from the event horizon.

Comment: OK, that sounds crazy, but I would still like an answer to my actual question which is talking about this effect happening on a universal scale. Is time dilation infinite inside the event horizon or just at it? Could Earth be near a body of mass producing such dilation without obvious observable effects such as the Earth being ripped to pieces?

Comment: Can you clarify your question to indicate whether the factor of two million is time running faster or slower? It is possible for time in other parts of the universe, e.g. near a black hole, to run two million times slower than on Earth. However it is not possible for time somewhere else to run much faster than on Earth.

Comment: My question asks about thousands of years of time passing on Earth while billions pass elsewhere, so slow on Earth fast elsewhere. If Earth was near a blackhole wouldn't time be going much faster elsewhere compared to it? At least Interstellar gave me the impression that is the way it works.

Comment: Yes, if you're allowed to move the Earth near a black hole you could make time run as slowly as you want. The physics in Instellar is basically fine. You might be interested to read [Kip Thorne's book on the subject](http://www.amazon.co.uk/The-Science-Interstellar-Kip-Thorne/dp/1494559390).

Comment: The choice of a factor of 2,000,000 for time dilation does not seem arbitrary.  An age of the universe divide by 2,000,000 would give an age of roughly 6,000 years, which is the age that most Young Earth Creationists believe the universe is.  And no, the Earth is not 6,000 years old.

Comment: @Sean Looks like you win the prize. The OP says "Don't ask me why, but you may be able to guess why...". Seems you showed that was true.

Comment: @Moss The age of Earth was not determined based on the age of the universe. It was determined by analyzing local objects, like rocks. Even if it were possible for the extremities of the observable universe to experience billions of years when we only experience thousands, we still know for a fact that the things on Earth (like the rocks) have experienced billions of years. And we're talking about rocks you can go and stand on, not things that are far removed from us

Comment: @Jimnosperm There are people who believe that radiometric dating is not reliable and there are alternate explanations for every geological appearance of age. I wanted to know something specifically about outer space, which is obviously old when you just look at it. There is a hypothesis about an expanding universe where there is crazy time dilation, but I asked my question before I realized that the hypothesis says that the conditions which caused the time dilation would no longer be present.

Comment: Please don't downvote the question for ideological reasons.

Comment: @Moss I haven't voted the question up or down. It's not a particularly bad question, I'm just trying to respond to the reason the question was asked. Radiometric dating is no nearly the only evidence on Earth of its age, but it is very reliable. There are even human archeological relics that predate 6000 years ago.

Comment: I could cite numerous phenomena in space that are obviously millions or billions of years old but it comes down to trust and belief. Either you trust science and its methods when it says Earth is billions of years old, or you don't trust us and believe it is far younger (possibly created to look old). If the former, you don't require more proof from us. If the latter, no amount of evidence would suffice. Denial is an easy weapon to wield and no evidence could oppose the circular "Yes, but it was created to look that way" argument (if that is a factor in this case).

Answer (score 1):

You must distinguish between proper time and observed coordinate time. Proper time is the time according to the clock of the particle/ of Earth. Proper time is always the shortest time observable - Example: According to the clock of an object one year has passed between two events happening on the worldline of this object. For observers this proper time period may be observed as being longer - we call it dilated. Time dilation is the dilation of time according to the frame of observers. That means for example that your own body's clock will always show your proper time which will never be dilated for you, but it may be dilated for observers.

First, let's consider time dilation of **Einstein's special relativity**. 1 Year of Earth time may be observed by a particle moving very near light velocity as one million years. Inversely, if this particle returns back to Earth after one year of its own proper time, one million years may have passed according to the Earth's reference frame.

This second phenomenon could have practical consequences in far future, if we are sending an astronaut to a far Galaxy. It has been calculated that a permanent acceleration equal to 1 g (simulating Earth gravity) would approach the astronaut very near to light velocity, permitting to visit another Galaxy within a lifetime, but at his return millions of years would have passed according to the clocks on Earth. I do not say that this will be possible one day, but these are limits of physical laws and arithmetics which are going much further than we could expect.

Secondly, there is time dilation of **general relativity**, in particular with regard to the event horizon at the Schwarzschild radius of a black hole.

An infalling observer will notice no particularity, according to his frame he is accelerated normally by gravitation towards the black hole.

In contrast, external observers will never see an infalling object cross the event horizon. The movement is dilated, and even after millions of years, we will still observe the object approaching the event horizon without passing it, even if the object crossed the event horizon already millions of years ago.

Comment: I don't understand everything you say, but it doesn't quite answer my question does it?

Comment: If you do not find the answer to your question, please specify what is missing. I answered your title question two times with "yes": once regarding special relativity, and once regarding general relativity.

Comment: OK, I didn't know that you were saying yes. Are you saying that if the Earth was moving very fast relative to everything else in the universe or if it is in a large gravity well then the dilation I am asking about could occur? If we were moving very fast wouldn't we see one side of the universe very blue shifted and the other very red? If we were in a gravity well how large/close would the mass have to be to Earth or our solar system in order to get the level of time dilation I am talking about?

Comment: Many ifs. Perhaps it might be interesting for you to know about the fact that on Earth we are nearly [comoving observers](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/156768/are-we-comoving-observers-of-space-expansion). - I have no answer for your gravity well question.